# Ensuring that opening data before awk condition is dealt with

Tags: awk, git-bash

I have XML which contains:

```
</body></text></xml>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheetv1_1.xsl" ?><text><body>
```

I need to split the file at each XML declaration.

I've been trying the following awk line, but it fails, and I don't know why. Any help gratefully received.

```
 awk '/<?xml v/{filename=NR".xml"}; {print >filename}' sourcefile.xml
```

where sourcefile.xml contains the data to be split.

I thought it might be an issue with escaping the question mark, but that seems not to be the issue.
The xml tag is preceded by \r\n

I'm using Gitbash for Windows.

What I need to end up with are a load of separate files, all of which end with

```
</body></text></xml>
```

and begin with

```
 <?xml version="1.0" etc
```

The shell responds with 'expression for `>' redirection has null string value' but I'm afraid I'm not sure what that means. I also get no output files at all.

Comment: Can you post sample output how you want to see.

Comment: The question mark most definitely should be escaped. A question mark in regex means that the preceding token is optional, so you are matching on `<xml v` as well as `xml v`. That second match is the one that is leading you to believe that it's working as intended.

Comment: Furthremore you say it "Fails". Does it error, are there output files missing that you believe should be there. What does "Fail" mean here.

Comment: Show us a representative sample with enough input for more than one output file, and show us exactly what the contents of the output files should be.

Comment: @JNevill   I've amended the question in response to your and others' comments. Many thanks for engaging with this.

Comment: @RamineniRaviTeja thanks for engaging; I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting means that your redirection out to a file is pointing to a filename that is undefined. Your `filename` variable is blank at some point during script execution.

Try setting that filename variable at the BEGIN block of the awk script to insure that the records occuring before your first `"<?xml v"` match has somewhere to go:

```
awk 'BEGIN{filename="prexmlgarbage.xml"} /<\?xml v/{filename=NR".xml"}; {print >filename}' sourcefile.xml
```

I've also added an escape character before the question mark so you are properly matching on the string `<?xml v`

You could also put a condition before your `print` block, if you don't want to capture records before your first `"<?xml v"` hit:

```
awk '/<\?xml v/{filename=NR".xml"}; filename!=""{print >filename}' sourcefile.xml
```

Comment: You're going to need `close(filename);` before `filename=...` if the input file is not tiny and and you aren't using GNU awk.